# Navigate from one page to another page when submit button is clicked using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

i am trying to navigate from one page to another in angularjs2 when submit button is clicked. i tried in navigating using navbars but it is not working when i tried to implement when button clicked?

### here is my code

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details.component';
import { Router,RouteConfig  } from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div>
  <input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="myName" (keyup.enter)="myName='' placeholder="enter ur Name" >
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Continue" (click)="clickName(Name); Name=''" > 
        </div>`,
  directives:[DetailsComponent]
})

@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/details',  component: DetailsComponent,  name: 'Details' }
  ])
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private router:Router){

 }
  clickName(name){
  console.log('in the clickName' + Name);
    this.router.navigate(['Details']);
  }}
```

### details.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'details',
  template: `<h1>In the second page of details form`

})

export class DetailsComponent{

}
```

these are my two components first component is Appcomponent is displaying the template of input that takes a name and when i submit it. i have to navigate in to an another page which contains some text().i just what to navigate it. please solve my query.i am trying this from the past 2 days

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your submit function as follows :

```
clickName(name){
    console.log('in the clickName' + Name);
    this.router.navigate(['details/']);    // pass route in the navigate function instead of Component Name
  }}
```

Comment: tried but showing this error report Component "AppComponent" has no route named "details"

Comment: @SukumarDhoni whats your version of angular router?

Comment: i dont know which version of angular router. how can i find that. it just came when i palced "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2", in packge.json

Comment: Try to update your angular 2 version to rc 5 and use the new router v3.0.x.. follow the guide for setup on rc5 as angular 2 v2.0.0 beta 2 is quite old. You will face issues later migrating the project to new version

Comment: hoo thanks! i wiil update that.can you please provide an example(plukner) on routing when button clicks @noor

Comment: @SukumarDhoni follow the angular 2 quickstart (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) for setting up the project with angular 2 rc 5 and setup your routes as described in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html .

Comment: I dont have a plunker ready but if you stick to the guide you will probably do it right

Comment: your function would work if you just use the right parameters ->
this.router.navigate(['/details']);

as for rc5, the angular router project is independent from the angular2-core, so updating the core to rc5 wont change a lot.
what you can do is update the core to rc.5 and the router to 3.0.0-rc.1, but the things you request also worked before. (although updating is recommended)

Comment: I am not able to access '@RouteConfig'. What should I import ?
My code looks like below :-
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'enroll',
    templateUrl: './enroll.component.html'
})

@RouterConfig([
  { path: '/enroll',
    component: EnrollComponent,
    name: 'enroll' 
 }])

export class EnrollComponent {
}

Answer (score 0):

use the routes path instead of the name:

this.router.navigate(['/details']);